# HTML DOM - New element taking wrong values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to be able to create many new elements at once with javascript, and give them each an onmousedown() function. But the variables I want to put through end up being used for every element. I've set up a jsfiddle to show what the problems is:

http://jsfiddle.net/XzFbD/

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) 
{
     var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
     newDiv.id = "newDiv" + x;
     newDiv.innerHTML = x;
     newDiv.onmouseover = function () {
          changeNumber(newDiv, x + 1);
     }

     var container = document.getElementById("myDiv");
     container.appendChild(newDiv);
}

function changeNumber(obj, newValue) {
     obj.innerHTML = newValue;
}
```

The functionality I want from this is so that every hovered number will increase its own number by 1. But All of their functions are being overwridden and changed to all use the last element and its number. How can I fix this please?

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XzFbD/2/

Comment: Thanks Arun :) I've added a bunch of "Function Factories" to my real code now.

Answer (score 1):

`for` does not contain `block scope`. Therefore a browser is really doing this to your code (hoisting):

`var newDiv;
for() { ... }`

That means your variable `newDiv` will be used and rewritten on every loop. When you hover, it will use the last set `newDiv` since it's all the same variable. You need to contain this into `block scope` by using a `function`. It will also be faster.

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) 
{
loop(x);
}

var loop = function(x) {

 var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
 newDiv.id = "newDiv" + x;
 newDiv.innerHTML = x;
 newDiv.onmouseover = function () {
      changeNumber(newDiv, x + 1);
 }

 var container = document.getElementById("myDiv");
 container.appendChild(newDiv);
};

var changeNumber = function(obj, newValue) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way

http://jsfiddle.net/XzFbD/4/

```
for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++) 
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = "newDiv" + x;
    newDiv.innerHTML = x;
    newDiv.onmouseover = function () {
        changeNumber(newDiv, x );
    }

    var container = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    container.appendChild(newDiv);
}

function changeNumber(obj, newValue) {
    obj.innerHTML = newValue;
}
```